# Change to Laravel Form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel

How to convert it Bootstrap to Laravel?

Bootstrap

```
<div class="form-group has-success">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess">Input success</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess">
</div>
```

Laravel

```
        <div class="form-group" has-success>
            {!! Form::label('name','Name:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('name', null,['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'inputSuccess','required']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('description','Description:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('description', null,['class'=>'form-control','required']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('price','Price:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('price', null,['class'=>'form-control','required']) !!}

        </div>
            {!! Form::submit('Save',['class'=>"btn btn-success"]) !!}
              </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I want it to edit the 
`{!! Form::label('name','Name:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('name', null,['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'inputSuccess','required']) !!}
        </div>`
but I dont know how to put inputSuccess in my form above

`<label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess">Input success</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess">
</div>`

Comment: On a side note, you do not HAVE to use Laravel Form. Laravel works perfectly fine without it, as they are just HTML generators. Personally I prefer not to use them for the exact reason, as it adds yet another Laravel dependency to the view.

Comment: Yes okay then Thanks. I am just new here. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<div class="form-group has-success">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess">Input success</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess">
</div>
```

to this

```
<div class="form-group has-success">
    {!! Form::label('inputSuccess', 'Input success', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    {!! Form::text('inputSuccess', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

> Form::label(1, 2)
>
> > 1 - name to for="" attribute.
> >     2 - displaying name of this label.
>
> Form::text(1, 2, 3)
>
> > 1 - input name (name="").
> >     2 - default value (optional).
> >     3 - input attributes. You can set either placeholder, maxlength, class, id CSS etc.

Read this for more informations about [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
<label class="control-label" for="name">First Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name=first_name>
</div>

<div>
{!! Form::label('name', 'First Name', ['class' => 'form-control'])     !!}
{!! Form::text('first_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Refer laravel [Forms & Html](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html)

```
<div class="form-group has-success">
        {!! Form::label('inputSuccess','Input success',array('class' => 'control-label')) !!}
        {!! Form::text('inputSuccess', null,
          array('required',
                'class'=>'form-control',
                 'id'=>'inputSuccess',
                'placeholder'=>'')) !!}

</div>
```